# Activity Recycling....Is this possible

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make an app for a contest...but I'm stuck right now!
I want to make an app like dictionary, which has many screens(up to 1000).
How can I make so many screens for particular data...without making so many activity?
   And if i go with making 1000 activity , what will happen??

Comment: What do you mean by 1000 screens? 1000 screens with distinct layout or same layout?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by 100 listview of image maybe this link will help https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-feed-example-using-php-mysql-volley/

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the layout of your app and change the data(using appropriate DB) instead of changing screens every time.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of an `Activity` as the action the user is performing in your app, not as the specific contents of a screen. So in your dictionary app, you probably only need two activities: one to list all the words, and another to show the definitions for the selected word.

Let's say you want to create `DefinitionActivity` to display the definition of a word. Probably you have the data saved somewhere, or can download it from the internet, or whatever. The important part is that you pass the word to display into this activity from your main activity. You can write something like this:

```
public class DefinitionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_SELECTED_WORD = "DefinitionActivity.EXTRA_SELECTED_WORD";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.definition_activity);

        String selectedWord = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_SELECTED_WORD);
        String definition = // load your definition, or pass it to the intent like above

        TextView wordView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        wordView.setText(selectedWord);

        TextView definitionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
        definitionView.setText(definition);
    }
}
```

When you start this activity from your main activity, you can pass the selected word in:

```
public void launchDefinition(String word) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefinitionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DefinitionActivity.EXTRA_SELECTED_WORD, word);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now you have one activity that can display the definition for any word. No need to create a separate activity for each word in the dictionary.